# how to set stylesheet for groupbox title in QT

Tags: qt

I have a widget with groupbox. I set the border for the groupbox using stylesheet that also works fine, but the border is not fit with the groupbox title. I searched in google, they suggest to change the groupbox title like:

```
QGroupBox::title { 
 background-color: transparent;
 subcontrol-position: top left; /* position at the top left*/ 
 padding: 2px 13px;
}
```

In my code i used the stylesheet like:

```
ui->groupBox->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid gray;"
                            "border-radius: 9px;"
                            "margin-top: 0.5em;");
```

so how to apply setstylesheet property for the groupbox title, guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply such stylesheet to parent of `groupBox`:

```
this->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox::title {"
                    "background-color: transparent;"
                    "padding-top: -24px;"
                    "padding-left: 8px;} ");
```

In my case it was `MainWindow`.

Also you can edit stylesheet from *QtDesigner* by calling "Edit styleSheet..." menu on required widget. I prefer to edit my `MainWindow` stylesheet to keep all code in one place.

In *QtDesigner* CSS will looks like this *(this is stylesheet of `QGroupBox` parent)*:

```
QGroupBox {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 9px;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

QGroupBox::title {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-top: -24px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: i used like groupBox->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox { border: 1px solid gray;border-radius: 9px;margin-top: 0.5em; } ""QGroupBox::title{subcontrol-origin: margin;subcontrol-position: top left;padding: 5 5px;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;}");