# Position of the title in Group Box

Tags: qt-designer, qtstylesheets, qgroupbox

I have a Group Box as follows:

[image]

```
QGroupBox{
    background-color: #000044;
    font: 12px consolas;
    color: cyan;
}
```

I wish the border to be more bluish, and then I get:

[image]

```
QGroupBox{
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    background-color: #000044;
    font: 12px consolas;
    color: cyan;
}
```

The title is not centered with the top border of the Group Box and I do not know how to do it.

**EDITED:**

The possible solution proposed by ekhumoro does not work. I miss the upper-left corner.

[image]

```
QGroupBox{
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    background-color: #000044;
    font: 12px consolas;
    color: cyan;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

QGroupBox::title {
    padding-top: -16px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

[image]

```
QGroupBox{
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    background-color: #000044;
    font: 12px consolas;
    color: cyan;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

QGroupBox::title {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-top: -16px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set stylesheet for groupbox title in QT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602021/how-to-set-stylesheet-for-groupbox-title-in-qt)

Comment: As I edited, the possible solution does not work.

Comment: It does work, you just have to find the right properties. It is impossible to create stylesheets that give the same results for all platforms and/or widget styles. It works for me using the `top` and `left` properties in the `QGroupBox::title` rule (and no `padding`).

Comment: how can I move the title to the right side of groupbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the tip ekhumoro. Now it works.

[image]

```
QGroupBox{
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    background-color: #000044;
    font: 12px consolas;
    color: cyan;
}

QGroupBox::title {
    top: -6px;
    left: 10px;
}
```